# Turn HTML string into a organized Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lang: Node JS

I'm using a Texteditor and I get the output string like this

```
<p>This is <strong>a <a href="#">test</a></strong></p>
```

but could be different HTML-tags like H1, H2, etc. but nothing more special than actual HTML text tags.

Now I want to turn that string into an object that I can work with and send to my database.
So the perfect way would it be transformed into something like this...

```
[{type: "text", text: "This is ", bold: false}, {type: "text", text: "a  ", bold: true}, {type: "link", text: "test", bold: true, href: "#}]
```

and so on.

I tried the Regex approach and split it by and do all sorts of logic to turn into a structured object but that can't be the best way to do it since it'll fail if I would in the future write `<h1>Test</h1>` in the middle of the text as an example.

How would you approach this?

Comment: to be able to do this you need to define your predefined rules, and a clear relation between the input and the expected output, as I can see, you ignored the second `<p>` and also ignored the `<a>` element, so your target is only paragraph elements that have content?

Comment: That was actually just an example and I missed the second <p> and <a> with purpose since I was too lazy to write out the whole object :D

Comment: What do you expect to get with an HTML like `<p>This is <a href="#">a <strong>test</strong></a></p>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go easy, [`jsdom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) or [`htmlparser2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2) and [`domhandler`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/domhandler) would help doing that. For example, using `htmlparser2` and `domhandler` (from [some of my apps](https://github.com/emibcn/covid-data/tree/master/bcn/src)):

```js
// Parsers helpers
import { Parser } from 'htmlparser2';
import { DomHandler } from 'domhandler';

// Get all text contents, recursively
const getAllText = (node) => {
  return node.children.map( n => {
    if (n.type === 'text') {
      return n.data.trim("\n\r ");
    }

    // Discard `small` tags
    if (n.name === 'small') {
      return ''
    }

    return getAllText(n);
  }).join('')
}

// Parses HTML data containing a UL/LI/A tree
const parseMenu = (data) => {

  const parseLink = (link) => {
    const name = getAllText(link);
    const code = link.attribs['data-value']?.trim("\n\r ");
    return {
      name,
      ...(code ? {code} : {}),
    }
  }

  const parseLi = (li) => {
    const ul = li.children.find(({type, name}) => type === 'tag' && name === 'ul' );
    const link = li.children.find(({type, name}) => type === 'tag' && name === 'a' );
    return {
      ...(link ? parseLink(link) : {}),
      ...(ul ? {children:  parseUl(ul)} : {}),
    }
  }

  const parseUl = (ul) => {
    return ul.children.filter(({type, name}) => type === 'tag' && name === 'li' ).map( child => {
      return parseLi(child);
    });
  }

  let result;
  const handler = new DomHandler( (error, dom) => {
    if (error) {
      // Handle error
    } else {
      // Parsing completed, do something
      result = parseUl(dom[0]);
    }
  });

  const parser = new Parser(handler);
  parser.write(data);
  parser.end();
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I really don't get on how to loop through an HTML string. Can you explain that a bit?
The problem is that I won't know from the beginning how the HTML will be structured and Cheerio wants me to always start with for example $('p') but the thing is that It can start with an <a> or a <h1> and so on.

Comment: In the example copied above, the parser expects the HTML to be a `<ul>` element with childs. If you need something more generic, you can get `dom[0]` (in the example) and start with a `switch(dom[0].tag)` instead of directly with `parseUl(dom[0])`. If everything can go into everything, this should go into a recursive function, probably named `parseDispatcher` (or something like that).

Comment: What does tools offer is to parse the HTML into a data structure which may be traversed or queried. Its up to you how to transform that into the data shape you need.

Comment: For example: Do you want a unique JSON object containing all objects into each other, as structured in the original DOM? Or maybe you want an array of objects, containing none or some of their child original DOM structure? Or you want separated arrays containing each one a type of objects found into the DOM?

Comment: But for example like this `<p>This is <strong>a <a href="#">test</a></strong></p>`. How are you able to follow the DOM object down for each step? When you know the HTML object from start it's, of course, easy since you can just use it next, etc. but when it'll differ every time it seems to be impossible. 

I just might go back to the regex split logic instead :P

Comment: I can improve the answer showing an initial example issuing your specific use case, but first I'd need you to answer what I asked in the previous comment.

Comment: That would be awesome! The final output should be an array of objects cointaing the DOM structure I want is the different tags in order so for example this string `<p>This is <strong>a <a href="#">test</a></strong></p>` would become `[{type: "text", text: "This is ", bold: false}, {type: "text", text: "a  ", bold: true}, {type: "link", text: "test", bold: true, href: "#}]`

Comment: Edited in the initial post so it's easier for you to read. Check the string and final output object there.

Answer (score 0):

Use cheerio library (or any other html parser library of your choise) and operate The "DOM Node" object as you wish.